# How perform this query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i need get all parents of all students that are enroled in primary school level.
My ER model is:

[image]
The table names are in spanish. The translations are:

- responsable == parent.
- alumno == student.
- tutelado == is the N:N relationship between parent and student.
- grado == class or course (i dont know the correct translation)
- nivel == is the level school (Kinder, Elementary (primary in Argentina), Middle, High, etc...)

I construct this query with QuerBuilder (inside Responsable repository):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
$qb->innerJoin('r.tutelados', 't')
   ->innerJoin('t.alumno', 'a')
   ->innerJoin('a.grado', 'g')
   ->where('g.nivel = :Nivel')
   ->setParameter('Nivel', $unNivel);
```

This is the raw SQL:

```
SELECT r0_.iduser AS iduser0, r0_.iduser AS iduser1
FROM responsable r0_
INNER JOIN tutelado t1_ ON r0_.iduser = t1_.responsable
INNER JOIN alumno a2_ ON t1_.alumno = a2_.iduser
INNER JOIN grado g3_ ON a2_.grado = g3_.idgrado
WHERE g3_.nivel =  'Primario'
```

I execute the SQL in PhpMyAdmin and also get empty resultset.

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('YourBundle:Responsable')
         ->createQueryBuilder('r')
         ->join('r.alumnos', 'a') // Check the name of the relation between alumno and responsable
         ->join('a.grado', 'g')
         ->join('g.nivel', 'n')
         ->where('n.nivel = ?1')
         ->setParameter(1, 'elementary')
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks i try do on this way.

Answer (score 0):

I forget join the "nivel" table:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
$qb->innerJoin('r.tutelados', 't')
   ->innerJoin('t.alumno', 'a')
   ->innerJoin('a.grado', 'g')
   ->innerJoin('g.nivel', 'n')
   ->where('n.nivel = :Nivel')
   ->setParameter('Nivel', $unNivel);
```